# How can I sort date perfectly

Tags: mysql

I was trying to sort the data in-order by date but it doesn't sort perfectly. I don't know if there's an error in the code.

Here's some of the data in character in my database:

```
March 5, 2016
March 17, 2016
August 9, 2017
April 2, 2016
July 5,2018
January 15, 2019
```

The query I used is:

```
SELECT * FROM reporting  ORDER BY date ASC
```

Result are:

```
April 2, 2016
August 9, 2017
January 15, 2019
July 5,2018
March 5, 2016
March 17, 2016
```

Expected Result:

```
March 5, 2016
March 17, 2016
April 2, 2016
August 9, 2017
July 5,2018
January 15, 2019
```

Comment: _Don't_ store your dates as text.  Instead, use one of the answers below and change the column to bona fide dates.

Comment: gonna take note about that Tim.

Comment: @GelSSy . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `str_to_date()` to convert your date field from string to datetime

```
SELECT * FROM reporting  ORDER BY str_to_date(`date`,'%M %d, %Y') ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

use date format

```
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, "%F-%d-%Y") as date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

For SQL Server:

`convert( varchar, [date], 120)` will convert your date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

```
 select * from reporting order by convert( varchar, [date], 120) asc
```

For MySQL:

```
 select * from reporting order by DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m-%e") asc
```

Comment: The OP never tagged with his database, but most of the time people would be using MySQL with PHP, not SQL Server.

Comment: the query you give doesn't sort the data.

Comment: @GelSSy: check now